# How to display the full name from mongodb as the input value

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, mongodb

I have this project am working on, fetching data from an api using ajax, each time I try to get the user full name from the database, I only get the first word of the name, how do I get the user full name from the database and inject as the value for the input tag.

Here is my code:

```
getProfile();
    //Get Profile
    function getProfile() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/users/me',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            crossDomain: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('Get Profile Successfully!')
                console.log(data)
                let profile_name = '';
                let view = '';
                    view += "<form class='needs-validation' id='forms' novalidate>";
                    view += "<div class='form-row'>";
                    view += "<div class='col-md-12 mb-3'>";
                    view += "<label for='validationCustom01'>Full Name</label>";
                    view += "<input type='text' class='form-control' id='validationCustom01' placeholder='Full Name' value="+data.name+">";
                    view += "</div>";
                    view += "<div class='col-md-12 mb-3'>";
                    view += "<label for='validationCustom02'>Email Address</label>";
                    view += "<input type='email' class='form-control' id='validationCustom02' value=" + data.email + "  disabled>";
                    view += "</div>";
                    view += "<div class='col-md-12 mb-3'>";
                    view += "<label for='validationCustom03'>Age</label>";
                    view += "<input type='number' class='form-control' id='validationCustomUsername' placeholder='Age' value=" + data.age + ">";
                    view += "</div>";
                    view += "<div class='col-md-12 mb-3'>";
                    view += "<label for='validationCustom03'>Password</label>";
                    view += "<input type='password' class='form-control' id='validationCustom04' placeholder='Password'>";
                    view += "</div>";
                    view += "<div class='col-md-12 mb-3'>";
                    view += "<label for='validationCustom03'>Repeat-Password</label>";
                    view += "<input type='password' class='form-control' id='validationCustom05' placeholder='Repeat-Password'>";
                    view += "</div>";
                    view += "<button class='btn btn-primary' type='submit'>Save</button>";
                    view += "</form>";
                    profile_name += " <p class='name'>"+data.name+"</p>";
                    profile_name += "<p class='role'>Task Manager</p>";

                $('.users-form').html(view);
                $('.profile_data').html(profile_name);

            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At `value="+data.name+"`, suppose data.name was `Cat Hat`; when the expression is evaluated, then it becomes `value=Cat Hat` - which makes the HTML parser thinks the first space is the start of a new attribute. **The solution is to add quotes around the value like so: `value='"+data.name+"'`.**

You should also HTML entities `name` so that you do not have a XSS vulnerability (data.name = `' onload=alert(1)`). Same goes to the rest of your templating.

Comment: No problem, be sure the data in your template does not introduce any possibility for XSS.

Comment: how do i get rid of XSS vulnerability

Comment: @SamsonUgwu HTML entities the data. `'` → `&apos;`, `"` → `&quot;`, etc. There are many node packages that can do this, just search `html entities` on npm. I hope that you can solve this

Comment: Ok I got, I wil try just that.